# Complete list of property that is used in Hadoop framework

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm making some research on the Hadoop framework. I would like to ask about the property that can be used in the framework.. For example

- io.sort.mb
- io.sort.record.percent
- etc

Is there any reference that I can can the whole properties list of this framework? Very hopefully that someone can help me.

Besides, I would like to ask if, is it any difference for io.sort.mb and mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb? Or they are just the same?

Comment: u can refer to hadoop the definitive guide for the details of properties. And these two properties arent the same. Please refer the same.

Comment: I've refer to the book and this question come from there.. I just think if there might be another than that, that are documented. Erm, refer to the same book, there's no explanation about mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb. I've found the property from the other site.. @aviral

Answer (score 6):

Here are complete list of configuration properties categorized by configuration files:

- Properties that go into [core-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml)
- Properties that go into [hdfs-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)
- Properties that go into [mapred-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)
- Properties that go into [yarn-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

And regarding your other question:

> is it any difference for io.sort.mb and mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb? Or they are just the same?

There are the same, except that `io.sort.mb` is deprecated from Hadoop 2.0.