# What are the properties for controlling the number of retries when connecting to HDFS

Tags: hadoop

When I try to connect to HDFS with an invalid URL I get a message of the form:

```
Retrying connect to server: <hostname>/<port>. Already tried <n> time(s); maxRetries=45
```

Which property in the Hadoop configuration controls the `maxRetries`?

Also is there an easy way to go about finding these properties (other than trying to google)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you found an answer. Just going to add that the most straightforward way to learn is probably to read the [Hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/).

At the bottom of this page (currently) there's a section called "configuration" that also lists these files and the available options.

Answer (score 3):

The following relevent properties are:

```
ipc.client.connect.timeout
ipc.client.connect.max.retries.on.timeouts
```

which I found from the answer at
[Complete list of property that is used in Hadoop framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232744/complete-list-of-property-that-is-used-in-hadoop-framework) by searching the the lists provided there.