# Sqoop import taking long time because of failed tasks

Tags: import, timeout, sqoop

We have a issue which occurs sometimes but recurrently. When we run sqoop import for particular table, sometimes it completes in 5 minutes. Sometime it takes 2.5 hrs. In this case, we always see a failed map task which took around 2 hrs 10 mins. Can you please help provide solution to fix this.

1) Failed task always fail with the following error. When the below error is expected to occur, can we fail the map task in 10-15 mins rather than waiting 2 hrs.

> "2018-03-06 00:09:41,485 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader: Top level exception: 
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1671)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1658)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1789)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:5031)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:4941)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:4917)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:5210)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readWrappedBytes(IOBuffer.java:5232)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readUnsignedShort(IOBuffer.java:5147)"

Attaching the log file for failed task.

Please help with solution.

[image]

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Obviously fixing the source of this error would be a better solution but the dirty workaround with timeouts should safe you some time for now.

You can specify generic hadoop options when using sqoop by defining them right after the tools name.
e.g sqoop import -Dmapred.map.max.attempts --connect ...

There are quite some options which might proof usefull in your case, but i guess you want something like mapred.task.timeout.

mapred.task.timeout:
"The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string"

for a full list of mapreduce related Attributes have a look here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html

More hadoop attributes are liked here: [Complete list of property that is used in Hadoop framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232744/complete-list-of-property-that-is-used-in-hadoop-framework)

Hope this helps